# what does "God's word for Today" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions

I am going to share some words of God irregularly on my Facebook page. So I want to give a name for this series of posts. A friend gives me a title: **God's Word for Today.**

Because I am not a native English speaker, I don’t know if this title can express my intention.
What does “God's Word for Today” mean to a native speaker?

Comment: Hello, Daisy. Firstly, the title has already been adopted, and probably copyrighted. But secondly, there's an implication that the author is certain about exactly what part of the Word (Scriptures in Christianity) God wishes to highlight at the time (day, season) in question.

Comment: Such short phrases often admit multiple interpretations. You'll need to use the explicit or implied context to determine which interpretation comes across strongest. For example, it could refer to a modern translation of the Bible, the latest in a series of daily oracles, or a selection of readings (produced for today) from God's Word.

Comment: @Lawrence - Maybe that ambiguity was a selling point.

Comment: Hi Daisy. It sounds to me as though you are intending to post quotes from a holy book (The Koran, The Bible, The Torah or Bhagavad Gita perhaps). Am I right or will your souce material be something else?